# Javascript - setting interval during object creation and referring to property using "this"

Tags: javascript, object, this, setinterval

i have two questions.

Is it possible to create interval for object method, inside this object?

Here is the code to better illustrate the question:

```
var Counter_01 = {
    start_number: 0,
    countUp: function() {
        document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = this.start_number;
        this.start_number++;
    },
    // is it possible to create interval for countUp function here?
}
```

Second question is, whether is it possible to run function during object creation, using interval inside object?

code:

```
function Counter() {
    this.start_number = 0;
    this.countUp = function() {
        document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = this.start_number; // code works when instead of "this.start_number" there is direct reference to the object name like "Counter_02.start_number"
        this.start_number++; // the same here
    }
    this.interval = setInterval(this.countUp, 1000);
}       
var Counter_02 = new Counter();
```

When this code is running, instead of incrementing number there appears only "NaN" in the web browser.

I was trying to pass the object name using parameter, but it wasn't working...

code:

```
function Counter( name ) {
    this.start_number = 0;
    this.countUp = function() {
        document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = name.start_number;
        name.start_number++;
    }
    this.interval = setInterval(this.countUp, 1000);
}
var Counter_02 = new Counter( 'Counter_02' );
```

How can i write code, that will allow to run interval during object creation, without refering directly to created object name?

I'm just getting started with javascript, and i will be grateful for help.

Comment: Try `this.countUp.bind(this)` in `setInterval`

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`setTimeout`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) function:

```
function Counter_01 () {
    this.start_number = 0,
    this.countUp = function() {
        document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = this.start_number;
        this.start_number++;
        setTimeout(this.countUp, 2000);//two seconds waiting
    }
    this.countUp();
}
```

If you need to add some arguments to `countUp`, use

```
setTimeout(function(){ this.countUp('argument') } , 2000);
```

Comment: It works when i changed "this.countUp" to "this.countUp.bind(this)" and manually run function for the first time using "Counter_01.countUp();".
I have one more question: is it possible to run function inside the object, instead of running it manually from outside?

Comment: Why don't you use function instead an object? So you can start "automatically" the countUp function. I edited my post.

Comment: This simple example that i attached here is not the main program that i want to create. This counter is just an example on which i wanted to present my problem. :)

Let's say that there is an object and it have 10 different functions. When object is created using "var object = {//some code};" is there way to make all the functions run automaticly?
Or it will be necessary to start them manually from outside?

For now i think that the best way to achieve what i want, is to use function that create object, like from my second example code and use there "this.countUp.bind(this)".